# <filter-mapping> a specific URL

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have 2 urls in the project, out of which I need `<filter-mapping>` to be applied for only one URL. Is that possible at all?
My URLs are:

> http://localhost:8080/MyDetails/MyContact
>
> http://localhost:8080/MyDetails/MyAddress

I need the `<filter-mapping>` applied to only first URL, but second URL should go through normal flow.

I have tried the below in my web.xml, but it doesn't work

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ContactFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.my.company.ContactFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ContactFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyDetails/MyContact</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the `<url-pattern>` like below

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ContactFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyContact</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```